# Sql group by and order by first date entered

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

I want to get the first datetime from the column datetime. The results is always the other way around. Using that query below, outputs the latest record. I want the opposite outputs of the latest record. How can I achieve the desired result?

```
name     datetime
John     August 23, 2015 03:50:01
John     August 23, 2015 03:50:14
Jane     August 23, 2015 04:51:11
Jane     August 23, 2015 05:00:11
```

The desired result should be

```
name  datetime
John  August 23, 2015 03:50:01
Jane  August 23, 2015 04:51:11
```

I'm using this query

```
SELECT * FROM person GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Perhaps by undertaking some basic research

Comment: Which database: MySQL or Oracle RDBMS?  Yes Oracle Corporation owns MySQL since it bought Sun, but the [oracle] tag is reserved for the database product not the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select p.*
from person p
where p.datetime = (select max(p2.datetime) from person p2 where p2.name = p.name);
```

Note:  if two rows have exactly the same `datetime` value, you will get both.

Answer (score 0):

You could `order by` that column in ascending order by add a `limit` clause:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     person
ORDER BY `datetime` ASC
LIMIT    1
```